# varchar2 fields empty in a oracle select with a entitymanager in java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have been wasting my time during 3 days looking for an answer for my problem.

I'm using hibernate and JPA. when i call find or findall method i obtain all the rows, but the field that are stored as varchar2 in database are empty, the numeric and date field are correct.

I'm using oracle 10g (the database that don't work) and i have tried with another database and it works perfectly.

When i try to save a new entity i get this error:

ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

only if i try to store string values, if i try to store date or number values it works prefectly, and if i use a where clause (with string values), it is filtered ok

I have tryed it in two computers, another databases, with netbeans and eclipse, with @namedqueries and native queries, and none work.

In toad or sqldeveloper if i run the query it works ok.

Is it a database problem? What's happening? what can i do?

Thank's a lot and sorry for my bad english.

I show you the code:

jBoss datasource:

```
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/datasources/ADIAPU" pool-name="ADIAPU" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.36.32.201:1521:segu</connection-url>
            <driver>oracle-thin</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>segu</user-name>
                <password>seguridad2</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ADIAPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasources/ADIAPU</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>  
            <property name="format_sql" value="true"/>  
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>                
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

GenericDao

```
package es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.AidaDescargas;

/**
 * 
 * @author
 */
// Session Bean
// Cada método actúa como una transacción
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> implements Serializable {
    private final static String UNIT_NAME = "ADIAPU";

    //@PersistenceContext(name = UNIT_NAME)
    @PersistenceContext(name="persistence/"+UNIT_NAME, unitName=UNIT_NAME)
    protected EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void save(T entity) throws Exception {
        try {
            em.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void delete(T entity) throws Exception {
        try {
            T entityToBeRemoved = em.merge(entity);
            em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public T update(T entity) throws Exception {
        T entityV = null;
        try {
            entityV = em.merge(entity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
        return entityV;
    }

    public T find(long entityID) throws Exception {
        try {
            return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public T find(String entityID) throws Exception {
        try {
            return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public List<T> findAll() throws Exception {
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
            return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // ery.getSingleResult()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T findOneResult(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters)
            throws Exception {
        T result = null;
        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

            // Method that will populate parameters if they are passed not null
            // and empty
            if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
                populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
            }

            result = (T) query.getSingleResult();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while running query: " + ex.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // ery.getSingleResult()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<T> findSeveralResults(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        List<T> results = null;

        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

            // Method that will populate parameters if they are passed not null
            // and empty
            if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
                populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
            }

            results = (List<T>) query.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while running query: " + ex.getMessage()
                    + ex.getClass());
            // e.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }

        return results;
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // ery.getSingleResult()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<T> findPrueba(String namedQuery) throws Exception {
        List<T> results = null;

        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
            results = (List<T>) query.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while running query: " + ex.getMessage()
                    + ex.getClass());
            // e.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }

        return results;
    }   

    private void populateQueryParameters(Query query,
            Map<String, Object> parameters) {

        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public String getUnitName() {
        return this.UNIT_NAME;
    }

}
```

DAO who call generic

```
package es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.AidaDescargas;
import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.AidaDescargasMedicos;
import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.AidaDescargasResidentes;
import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.DescargaFirma;



/**
 * 
 * @author
 */
@Stateless
public class DescargaFirmaDAO extends GenericDAO<DescargaFirma> implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DescargaFirmaDAO() {
        super(DescargaFirma.class);
    }   
}
```

and the BEAN

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.controller.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.dao.DescargaFirmaDAO;
import es.jcyl.sacyl.desc.model.entity.DescargaFirma;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 * 
 * @author 07988518C
 */

@ManagedBean(name = "colectivoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ColectivoBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EJB
    private DescargaFirmaDAO dfDAO; 


    public ColectivoBean() {

    }

    public void firmar(){

        DescargaFirma descargaFirma = new DescargaFirma();

        descargaFirma.setCategoria_tipo("CATEGORIA");
        descargaFirma.setColumna("COLUMN");
        //descargaFirma.setColectivo(idColectivo);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        descargaFirma.setFecha(new Date());

        descargaFirma.setNif("12345678");
        descargaFirma.setId_descarga_firma(new Long("1"));

        //descargaFirma.setNif("D");

        try {
            dfDAO.findAll();
            dfDAO.save(descargaFirma);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

database fields

```
ID_DESCARGA_FIRMA   NUMBER
CATEGORIA_TIPO  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
COLECTIVO   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
FECHA   DATE
NIF VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)
COLUMNA VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

Comment: Can you include your entity object and your table in your question, please?

Comment: Have you searched for the meaning of the ORA-01461 error message?

Comment: Yes, i have search ORA-01461 error but have nothing to do with my problem, only with CLOB datatype  and field that store more than 4k characters (not my case).
The entity object and table i'll include it after 9 hours because i don't have my code here. Sorry and thank's again

Comment: Sorry for my expolanation. I have tried with 2 different driver, ojdbc6 and ojdbc14. I'm using oracle 10g (the database that don't work) and with another database (oracle 10g too) it works well. I have put my code in first post

Comment: Post the INSERT statement that your JPA implementation is using. FWIW I don't see a point in doing a findAll and ignoring what it returns

Comment: The code of your entity and the definition of your tables are crucial information that are still missing.

Comment: Finally we migrate the database to a new one and now it works all. Thank's for all =)